# Taking a Windy (leaflet) screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, leaflet

I am new to StackOverflow and wanted to ask a question regarding taking a screenshot of a div.

I am using Windy API to display some information on my web page, I have used HTML2Canvas and dom-to-image to take a screenshot of a div.

This is what the screenshot should look like:
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQEWe.jpg)

This is what I'm getting from the windy/leaflet map container div:

[dom-to-image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DfCP.png)

As you can see, are the particles missing in the second screenshot.

These particles are generated dynamically and do not seem to have divs, is this the reason the second screenshot is missing them. Has anyone tried to work with windy API and may point out where these particles are located in the HTML file.

I can't seem to figure out what code or file to add here, if you need any let me know.
Thanks in advance!